# PWA support in Angular throws node_modules/@angular/service-worker/service-worker.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3 error

Tags: angular, typescript, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I am integrating PWA in my Angular project. Its gives error While registering `ServiceWorkerModule` in `app.module.ts`

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
 ...
 ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
 ]
})
```

When I run `ng build --prod` is giving me this error

> ERROR in ./src/main.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/app/webel/src/main/webapp/webel/src'
>   ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /app/webel/src/main/webapp/webel/node_modules/@angular/service-worker/service-worker.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
>   at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (/app/webel/src/main/webapp/webel/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25616:34)
>       at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (/app/webel/src/main/webapp/webel/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25404:46)
>       at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (/app/webel/src/main/webapp/webel/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25385:14)
>       at /app/webel/src/main/webapp/webel/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24241:30
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at extractProgramSymbols (/app/webel/src/main/webapp/webel/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24240:79)
>       at AotCompiler.analyzeModulesAsync (/app/webel/src/main/webapp/webel/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23796:47)
>       at CodeGenerator.codegen (/app/webel/src/main/webapp/webel/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:32:14)
>       at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (/app/webel/src/main/webapp/webel/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:73:30)
>       at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then (/app/webel/src/main/webapp/webel/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:428:58)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)

I am using versions as below,

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.7.3"
"ng-pwa-tools": "0.0.15"
"@angular/service-worker": "^6.0.1"
"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.4"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: npm install....

Comment: @ritaj no luck with npm install.

Comment: what is your angular- compiler dependency version. error is originating in it

Comment: `npm i --save @angular/service-worker@<version>` set the same version of angular. e.g `@angular/service-worker": "^5.2.0`

Comment: @bhavesh27 its `"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.4"`

Comment: change angular-compiler version 4 to version 3

Comment: @bhavesh27 There is no version with 3 for angular-compiler Check this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/compiler

Comment: rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json && npm install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating completely to angular 6.0 solved the issue. Though `rxjs` has some breaking changes in 6.0, This can be solved either by migrating to the latest version or can be immediately fixed by adding `rxjs-compat` (Backword compatibility)